# Prisma - Set property's type as array of enum

Tags: database, mongodb, prisma

This is my model:

```
model ExampleModel {
  id   String @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  name String @unique
  foo  ...
}

enum Tags {
  TagA
  TagB
  TagC
}
```

I want to set the type of `foo` as an array of Tags, (an example value of `foo` would be `['TagA', 'TagC']`. How do I do that? Using `foo Tags[]` sets the type of `foo` as `"TagA"[] | undefined`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to make `foo` an array of `Tags` enum, you can indeed use `foo Tags[]`. However, the type "TagA[] | undefined" means that foo can be an array of TagA, or it can be undefined (not set). This is the expected type when you define an array field in Prisma, but it is not required and does not have a default value.

If you want foo to always have a value (i.e., it can never be undefined), you can make it a required field by appending the `@default` directive with an empty array as a default value, like so:

```
model ExampleModel {
  id   String @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  name String @unique
  foo  Tags[] @default([])
}

enum Tags {
  TagA
  TagB
  TagC
}
```

In this revised schema, `foo` is a required field that defaults to an empty array if no value is provided. It will always be an array of Tags, never undefined.